# MYSQL cumulative sum by player

Tags: mysql

Im having a table with players and their scores. I managed to create a query to get the cumulative sum. I want the query to group this cumulative sum by player, so that the cumulative sum of the previous players is not included to start with the cumulative sum of the new player. An example of the result I get with my current query:

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| player | total  | cumul |
+--------+--------+-------+
| Arne   |     16 |    16 |
| Arne   |    -48 |   -32 |
| Arne   |     13 |   -19 |
| Arne   |    -17 |   -36 |
| Arne   |      7 |   -29 |
| Arne   |     41 |    12 |
| Arne   |    -30 |   -18 |
| Arne   |     -6 |   -24 |
| Arne   |     18 |    -6 |
| Bjorg  |     -5 |   -11 |
| Bjorg  |      9 |    -2 |
| Bjorg  |    -38 |   -40 |
| Bjorg  |    -12 |   -52 |
| Bjorg  |     11 |   -41 |
| Bjorg  |      3 |   -38 |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

How it should look like:

```
 +--------+--------+-------+
 | speler | total  | cumul |
 +--------+--------+-------+
 | Arne   |     16 |    16 |
 | Arne   |    -48 |   -32 |
 | Arne   |     13 |   -19 |
 | Arne   |    -17 |   -36 |
 | Arne   |      7 |   -29 |
 | Arne   |     41 |    12 |
 | Arne   |    -30 |   -18 |
 | Arne   |     -6 |   -24 |
 | Arne   |     18 |    -6 |
 | Bjorg  |     -5 |    -5 |
 | Bjorg  |      9 |     4 |
 | Bjorg  |    -38 |   -34 |
 | Bjorg  |    -12 |   -46 |
 | Bjorg  |     11 |   -35 |
 | Bjorg  |      3 |   -32 |
 +--------+--------+-------+
```

The problem with the first table is that the second player uses the cumul of the previous player to start from. How should I alter my query in order to switch between players?

Here's my query:

```
SELECT t.player,
     t.total,
     @running_total := @running_total + t.total AS cumul
FROM ( SELECT player, id, sum(punten) as total FROM `whiteboard_games` 
WHERE 1 group by player, id) t
JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) table1
ORDER BY t.player, id
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have a unique id in the `whiteboard_games`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query

```sql
select 
    @score:=if(@prevPlayer = player, @score+total, total) as cumil,
    total, 
    @prevPlayer:=player as player 
from
    (select * from tbl order by player) a join 
    (select @score:=0, @prevPlayer:='') b
```

**Results**:

```
| CUMIL | TOTAL | PLAYER |
--------------------------
|    16 |    16 |   Arne |
|    34 |    18 |   Arne |
|    28 |    -6 |   Arne |
|    -2 |   -30 |   Arne |
|    39 |    41 |   Arne |
|    46 |     7 |   Arne |
|    29 |   -17 |   Arne |
|    42 |    13 |   Arne |
|    -6 |   -48 |   Arne |
|    11 |    11 |  Bjorg |
|    -1 |   -12 |  Bjorg |
|   -39 |   -38 |  Bjorg |
|   -30 |     9 |  Bjorg |
|   -35 |    -5 |  Bjorg |
|   -32 |     3 |  Bjorg |
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1d62/3)**

Comment: I think he means to calculate cumul on the fly. In your sql fiddle you have a table with three columns. If so, then it is sufficient to write `select * from tbl` right?